# jquery bind not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below, which renders a calendar. However, bind is not detecting the change when the user clicks a date.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="/jq-mo-datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    //reset type=date inputs to text
    $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.page.prototype.options.degradeInputs.date = true;
    });
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jq-mo-datepicker/jQuery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/jq-mo-datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>


<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mobile.css" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#date").bind("change", function() {
            console.log($(this).val());
        });

});
</script>
```

Then in the body I have:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="date">Date Input:</label>
                            <input type="date" name="date" id="date" value=""  />
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I detect the value in the input element when a user clicks a different date?

Thanks to help from Loyalar, the problem as been narrowed to this:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
```

**When that file is included, you cannot bind. When it is excluded you can.**

Is there any other way I can read the value in the date id when the user clicks the calendar? Seems like this should be easy to do.

Comment: Have you tried using `.live` instead of `.bind`?

Comment: Just tried it there, and also nothing...no console log output.

Comment: Is it possible for you to make a JSFiddle example?

Comment: @Loyalar `.live` is deprecated and should not be used anymore (although he's using a very old version of jQuery).

Comment: @blex yes, since jQuery 1.7, but as you can see from the code example, he is using jQuery 1.5.2.

Comment: You could try [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) method to fire the change event.

Comment: I tried that here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129652/onselect-not-working-jquery-mobile-datepicker and it is not working either. That is why I am trying bind.

Comment: I made a JSFiddle example for you including the files (I presume) you are using - [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/snh4tk8r/2/). Changing the date in this fiddle writes a message in the console.

Comment: Thanks Loyalar, really appreciate that. The     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
 file was missing from the example on JSFiddle. I added it and now it is not working...

Comment: Alright, cool! Happy to help.

Comment: So the problem is in the jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js file....

Comment: You're using pretty old versions of both jQuery and jQuery mobile. Does it function as expected if you update them to more recent version?

Comment: The bind works, but there is no styled calendar rendered at all, so not really usable.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work was to detect a user click on a calendar cell, and then read the date from the #date field.

```
$('.ui-body-c').click(function(){
                console.log('user clicked on a date');
                console.log($("#date").val());
            });
```